# syntax error for If and Else statements

Tags: python, if-statement

enter image description hereOk, I am just starting to learn python, and I can't figure out why my IF/Else statement keeps getting this error after I enter Else: "SyntaxError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level". Here is my code
    if  x>1000:
        print('3')
    else:

SyntaxError:SyntaxError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

## the if and else are on the same column, so I am not sure whats  happening?

Here is the error (link below)
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPeh6.png)
Here was the solution: kind-af funny looking, but even though If was initially on column 4 python registered it as column 0, so I had to put my else: on column 0 (even though it didn't look aligned. THANKS EVERYBODY FOR THE HELP!!
[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwnp5.png)

Comment: The edit history suggests you might have done something weird in interactive mode. Remember that Python isn't looking at whether the lines line up right visually; it's looking at the actual whitespace characters you used.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, IDLE. You have tried to enter this into shell, right? So the thing looks like

```
>>> if x > 1000:
        print(3)
    else:
```

right? The point is, `>>>` doesn't count when calculating indents. So in fact if and else are *not* in the same column as far as IDLE is concerned. :-( [The indents it sees are 0, 8, 4.] You have to start the `else:` flush completely to the left margin.

Comment: Does IDLE just not do the `...` thing?

Answer (score 1):

Each indentation level should have four spaces.

```
if x > 1000:
    print('3')
else:
    pass  # Must match indentation level of `print('3')` above.


Python 3.5.2 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:52:12) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 4.2 (clang-425.0.28)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> x = 50
>>> if x > 100:
...     print('3')
... else:
...     pass
... 
>>> x = 150
>>> if x > 100:
...     print('3')
... else:
...     pass
... 
3
```

Thanks to the pointer from @Vekyn regarding IDLE indentation quirks:

[image]

Comment: but every time i press enter after entering else: the syntax error pops up before I can even put in an argument?

Comment: Which environment?  iPython?

Comment: @BenShapiro You're mixing spaces and tab?

Comment: python 3.5.2 shell (IDLE) on a Mac

Comment: it won't even let me get passed the "else:" term. I could tab my way to a new line and put "pass" into the argument equal level with "print" but the same error will pop up.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with spaces and tabs, even if lines look visually indented, from python perspective they maybe are not indented

[image]

For example, look at the image, line 2 contains 4 spaces and line 6 contains one tab. It's really useful when your text editor allows you to notice these differences somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably mixing up spaces and tabs. Only use one of those. If you are using spaces, make sure you are using the same amount of spaces. Also else must have something in it, like pass or return

Comment: "On the same column."  PLEASE do not use a language that assigns meaningful semantics to white space. This is one of my chief complaints about Python.  Plus, tabs or spaces per se?  Now we see the lexical analysis getting mixed up with terminal line discipline (that means, among other things, how control characters are mapped and interpreted by the upper half) issues.  This is not 1966.